# Access WordPress API Outside of WordPress (command-line PHP)

Tags: api, command-line

I have a PHP script that I need to run as a cron job.  However this script needs access to the WP API (`get_pages()`, `get_post_meta()` and `get_permalink()` specifically).  I've followed the instructions at http://codex.wordpress.org/Integrating_WordPress_with_Your_Website, but to no avail.

Code:

```
require_once('../../../wp-blog-header.php');
$args = array(
    'child_of' => 2083
);
$pages = get_pages($args);
```

However when I run `php -q this_file.php` from the command-line I get the following output:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Database Error</title>

</head>
<body>
    <h1>Error establishing a database connection</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Anyone have any thoughts/suggestions?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

WordPress expects the $_SERVER variables to be setup as if it were a normal web request.  Also, I would suggest loading wp-load.php instead of wp-blog-header.php since you probably don't need the WP class or the template loader to run.  Here is how I normally start any scripts I need to interact with WP from command line:

```
define('DOING_AJAX', true);
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
$_SERVER = array(
    "HTTP_HOST" => "mysite.com",
    "SERVER_NAME" => "mysite.com",
    "REQUEST_URI" => "/",
    "REQUEST_METHOD" => "GET"
);
require_once('current/wp-load.php');
```

**Update 2018:**

Nowadays Wordpress doesn't require $_SERVER at all.  If you simply need to access Wordpress API functions (e.g. to read/write to the database), all you need is:

```
require_once('current/wp-load.php');

# your code goes here...
```

Comment: To use `get_pages`, he does need the WP class. so wp-blog-header.php was the right file to call.

Comment: Tried doing exactly as you've specified here with the correct `HTTP_HOST`, `SERVER_NAME` and `REQUEST_URI`. Also tried with both `wp-blog-header.php` and `wp-load.php`.  Same error message as stated in original question in all instances. I'm running this from my theme directory - does that matter?

Comment: @goldenapples, he needs it to load, but he doesn't need it to run, which is the extra stuff that wp-blog-header.php does.

Comment: @dosboy, are you running this on a server or a development computer running mamp?  If you're running it on a computer that has more than one instance of mysql installed,  there is a chance that your environment may be using a different php and mysql instance from the command line than it does with normal http requests.

Comment: Hmm... clever thinking. It is a dev box running MAMP. But I don't have SSH access to my production box. Any idea how to specify a MySQL instance on my dev machine just to make sure the script is working?

Comment: There are two ways, if you're just running the file as an executable, change the #!/[current path to php] you're using to #!/[mamp's path to php].  Or if you're executing this by calling php your-file.php, then change the php to the path of mamp's php instead.

Comment: Thanks! That was the issue. FYI I also had to `chmod +x` on MAMP's version of php in order to run it via command-line. And the path (in case anyone else is looking for it) was `/Applications/MAMP/bin/php5.2/bin` (or `.../php5.3/bin`).

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [WP-CLI](https://github.com/wp-cli/wp-cli) [`eval-file`](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/eval-file/) command:

```
@daily /usr/bin/wp --path=/path/to/wp/ eval-file /path/to/that_file.php
```

This will first load the WP environment, then run your file.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer by @prettyboymp is about the most helpful and unique information about accessing wordpress from a php script that I have found on the web. It worked perfectly for me with WP core 3.7.1, then 3.9 broke it.

The problem was that `wp-load.php` changed the way it tested the `REQUEST_URI` for a valid path.  But fortunately it also added a new filter to allow short-circuiting the test.

So to restore the functionality of the answer in 3.9, I added `define('SUNRISE', 'on');` to `wp-config.php`, and created file `wp-content/sunrise.php` with this content:

```
add_filter('pre_get_site_by_path', 'my_pre_get_site_by_path', 10, 5 /*null, $domain, $path, $segments, $paths*/ );
    function my_pre_get_site_by_path($input, $domain, $path, $segments, $paths) {
    if ($path == '/') {
        return get_blog_details(array('domain' => $domain, 'path' => PATH_CURRENT_SITE), false);
    }
    return $input;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A variation to @prettyboymp's answer could be:

```
if(in_array(php_sapi_name(), ['cli', 'cli-server'])) {
    foreach($_SERVER as $key => $val) {
        if(!getenv($key))
             putenv($key.'='.$val);
    }

    if(!getenv('HTTP_HOST'))
        putenv('HTTP_HOST='.gethostname());

    if(!getenv('SERVER_ADDR'))
        putenv('SERVER_ADDR='.gethostbyname(gethostname()));

    if(!getenv('REQUEST_URI'))
        putenv('REQUEST_URI=/');

    if(!getenv('REQUEST_METHOD'))
        putenv('REQUEST_METHOD=GET');
}
```